# how to fix 404 not found error nginx on docker?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to make docker file run in to react app.react app all ready successfully deploy but page reload get an error 404 nginx error.

**this is my docker file**

```
FROM nginx:1.19.4-alpine
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY build-qa /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Depends on your app, but you most likely need an nginx.conf in there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be React Router DOM issue with nginx. Might check if you have the nginx.conf (local)

```
# nginx.conf
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  #tcp_nopush     on;
  
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  #gzip  on;
  #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
}
```

Then try build the image and run. Sample Dockerfile content:

```
FROM nginx
# FROM node:8 as react-build

WORKDIR /usr/share/react

RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

RUN rm -r /usr/share/nginx/html/*

RUN cp -a build/. /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Build Image
# docker build . -t <your-app-tag>:latest
# Run Container
# docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80/tcp --name <your-app-name> <your-app-tag>
```